# Building only a small subset of project using autotools

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf

I have a large project using autotools that contains some code that builds into a utility library. The project has quite a few dependencies and I would like to compile a specific subset of that utility library for mobile environments (Android/iOS). I expect a lot of dependencies to be unnecessary for that particular subset of functionality, and compiling the whole project for those architectures/platforms is impossible for technical reasons.

This mini version of the library would actually be useful not just to me but other people, as well. This is why the maintainer of the project suggested introducing a `--enable-mini` flag for the `configure` script. After experimenting a little (I have never done anything inside a `configure.ac` before) I actually got a build working that builds this extra *mini* library.

Now to the point: Is there a clean way to exclude all the other project executables and libraries from being built? What I want is a `./configure --enable-mini` invocation that will result in only the `libutilmini.a`/`libutilmini.la` being built. Sure, there are some components that could be disabled via `--disable-X` options, but obviously the project was not set up in a way that makes **all** components optional. Apart from the fact that it does not seem necessary to build everything else just to build the mini library, the whole project will not build for, for instance, the iOS platform.

I really would like to avoid adding an `if HAVE_MINI [...]` to all the `Makefile.am`s in every subdirectory, especially since the mini library is not useful to most of the other developers, this does not seem like an elegant approach. Are there any recommended ways of achieving these goals?

I am aware I could just create a new project using the sources I need and build those, but as I said the mini library *is* useful  to *some* other developers, too.

Comment: if components are not optional, they are most likely mandatory...so you *should* build them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to conditionally compile something with automake using a regular `make` command with no arguments, you *have* to use automake conditionals (the `if HAVE_MINI` thing you refer to); there is no other way. However, what you *can* do, alternatively, is to create an extra target (say, `build_mini`) in your toplevel `Makefile.am` which depends on everything needed to build your `libmini`. You could then tell people that if they want to build `libmini` (and nothing else), they don't run `make`, but they run `make build_mini`. This would look something like:

(toplevel Makefile.am)

```
SUBDIRS = foo bar baz
build_mini:
        $(MAKE) -C foo libmini-depends
        $(MAKE) -C bar libmini.la
```

or some such (the details would depend on what is needed to build libmini.la).

You would then have bar/Makefile.am look something like this:

```
if WANT_MINI
lib_LTLIBRARIES += libmini.la
endif
libmini_la_SOURCES = # ...
```

the only thing that really needs to be inside the conditional is adding the libmini.la to lib_LTLIBRARIES; everything else can be unconditional. So with this method, you should have only one `if FOO...endif` construct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will give it a shot. I would prefer something that can be influenced by `configure`, though. It somehow feels more familiar...

Comment: Conditionally not compiling something without using conditionals is, unsurprisingly, not possible...